# create bar chart with expression as values

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, ireport, bar-chart, calculated-columns

I usually create chart with Passing map object from *Java* code and in *iReport* using sub data set I create the chart.

Now I need to create a bar chart from calculated values of other fields of same report. For example one of the text box calculated value is

```java
new java.lang.Double((Double.valueOf( $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("budget_labour_cost").toString()).doubleValue()) 
            + (Double.valueOf( $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("budget_ico_cost").toString()).doubleValue()) 
            + (Double.valueOf( $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("budget_subcon_cost").toString()).doubleValue()) 
            + (Double.valueOf( $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("budget_oth_purchase_cost").toString()).doubleValue()) 
        )
```

I need to use the result of the expression in one bar of bar chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use a dataset; simply collect the results of the text fields in a variable (type list or map), then create a new datasource from this for your dataset.

The variable might use an expression similar to

$V{variable}.add() ? $V{variable} : $V{variable}

Calculation type "Nothing".